# SQL LEFT OUTER JOIN with Count

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have this query here:

```
SELECT a.timeSlot, a.dateSlot, COUNT(concat(b.dateSlot, ' - ', b.timeSlot)) AS counter 
FROM CP_VIP_Preview_TimeSlots as a 
   LEFT OUTER JOIN [CP-VIP-Preview] as b 
                ON a.timeSlot = b.dateSlot 
               AND a.dateSlot = b.timeSlot 
GROUP BY a.timeSlot, a.dateSlot, a.[order] 
ORDER BY a.[order]
```

What I am trying to do is get a count of each, which this query does, but something is messed up, any rows that have 0 appear as 1 and any row that actually has an items show the correct number, my problem if the row count is 0 its displaying 1....why is it doing that?

Comment: If you are trying to count only non-NULL values from b, stop using CONCAT, since it will never return NULL even for non-matching rows or if both inputs are NULL.  Compare `SELECT COUNT(CONCAT(NULL,'.'));` to `SELECT COUNT(NULL + '.');`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `COUNT(concat(b.dateSlot, ' - ', b.timeSlot))` will always return at least one

Perhaps you can try

```
sum(IIF(b.dateSlot is null,0,1))
```

Comment: It will return 1 but not because it's a count, rather because CONCAT will not allow any NULL output. You can get 0 if you stop using CONCAT. I like the SUM/IsNull better, but be careful: if dateSlot is a date/time column, 0 will convert 1900-01-01, which will break your SUM. Using `COUNT(b.dateSlot + ' - ' + b.timeSlot)`, or using a `CASE` expression, would be more reliable.

Answer (score -1):

you need to use a HAVING for apply a filter after use group by, that way you do not count the records zero

```
SELECT a.timeSlot, a.dateSlot, COUNT(concat(b.dateSlot, ' - ', b.timeSlot)) AS counter 
FROM CP_VIP_Preview_TimeSlots as a 
   LEFT OUTER JOIN [CP-VIP-Preview] as b 
                ON a.timeSlot = b.dateSlot 
               AND a.dateSlot = b.timeSlot 
GROUP BY a.timeSlot, a.dateSlot, a.[order] 
ORDER BY a.[order]
```

> HAVING COUNT(concat(b.dateSlot, ' - ', b.timeSlot)) > 0

Comment: I tried adding HAVING, but it did not work, its showing 1 when its 0